# Почему merge request создал бесполезный merge коммит?

Tags: git, gitlab

На gitlab был создан merge request. Этот merge request состоял из нескольких коммитов. Когда фича была готова, сделали approve этого merge request. Так же нажали галочку "squash commits", чтобы все коммиты объединить в один.

В результате получилось это:
[image: graph]

Предпоследний коммит - это коммит, созданный в результате squash. А последний коммит это merge коммит, который бесполезный. Оба эти коммиты были созданы автоматически gitlab. Зачем последний merge нужен?

Comment: `squash` создаёт **вашу** нить с одним коммитом. Без `merge` ваши дополнения в **главной** нити **не** появятся. Всё же нарисовано графом на экране.

Comment: но ведь можно было сделать fast-forward там

Comment: Поставьте опцию быстрого слияния. [How to prevent Gitlab from creating extra merge commit on branch merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48108507)

Comment: оооо спасибо! респект